# Estilo de carrosel com 3 slides

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, bxslider, carousel

Estou tentando fazer um tipo de slider onde aparece o slide do meio como principal e os laterais vão cortando de acordo com a resolução, mas eu estava com problemas no `IE` e por incrível que pareça a cliente usa `IE8`. Para mostrar o que eu quero só dar uma olhada `http://www.theva.com.br/teste`

Tentei usar este bxslider, já mexi tanto nele que já não sei se usar ele de fato vai resolver o problema, pelo menos por enquanto seria apenas estes 3 slides
Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Screenshots: http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/fcdbeaba0e7ce8485df57d0f9d3e06a27d185755

**----------- Update 06/03 ---------------**

> É, continuo com dificuldades, não sei se falta só uma coisa, mas
>   continua com o posicionamento errado no IE8, tentei adequar o CSS de acordo
>   resposta mas deve ter um parametro errado. O plugin altera o css por
>   inline o que vi é que o tratamento pro IE é diferente, que altera o *left* enquanto pro resto altera usando o *transformation* do css

**----------- Update 07/03 ---------------**

> Fiz um IF especialmente para IE abaixo do 10 com um margin-left diferente, mas o problema que o ajuste com a resolução de tela :/

**----------- Update 07/03 ---------------**

> Na realidade o problema está quando muda a resolução, vou mudar de plugin, que este só deu dor de cabeça, srsr

Comment: Seria ideal se você compartilhasse telas - afinal muita gente aqui está por trás de proxies. Melhor ainda seria se seu código (a parte em que está "empacado") fosse postado também.

Comment: screenshots Chrome e IE 9 e 8 http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/79363824440a13c873c2a89dd112cbc40afb665e (O chrome só funciona normal numa resolução um pouco maior), mas no mais postei o site para dar uma checada
Sobre os script's, acho que estou empacado em tudo, srsrs, já não sei o que posso fazer para resolver

Comment: Na realidade seria esse http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/fcdbeaba0e7ce8485df57d0f9d3e06a27d185755 eu tinha feito a alteração que tirei o margin-left que centralizava de acordo com a resolução... mas o problema que no IE ele não fica centralizado corretamente

Answer (score 8):

Pelo que vejo analisando o DOM da página cujo [link forneceste](http://www.theva.com.br/teste) na pergunta, o teu problema está nos estilos de CSS para os elementos dentro de cada `li` do teu *slider*.

Eis uma lista de alterações para "normalizares" a maneira como estás a manipular os elementos de forma a que nos diversos navegadores consigas atingir o mesmo aspecto visual:

1. #### O elemento que envolve o conteúdo

   No elemento `div` que envolve o conteúdo, para além de definires a largura e altura do mesmo, deves indicar que os elementos dentro dele estão todos relativos a ele:

   ```css
   .slide {
       height: 541px;
       width: 912px;
       position: relative;
   }
   ```
2. #### Os elementos que dividem a apresentação

   Tens dois elementos `div` que tratam de arrumar o texto para o lado esquerdo e a imagem para o lado direito. Estes elementos devem estar a ocupar um determinado espaço de forma eficaz sem permitirem misturas entre eles:

   ```css
   /* Definições para ambas as DIV (nova declaração) */
   .bxslider li .slide > div {
       position:absolute;
       top:80px;
       bottom:40px;
   }

   /* Definições para a DIV do texto */
   .slide_txt {
       left: 60px;
       color: #FFF;
       font-family: Helvetica-nw;
       font-size: 16px;
       text-align: left;
       width: 320px;
   }

   /* Definições para a DIV da imagem */
   .slide_img {
       right: 50px;
       width: 460px;
   }
   ```

   Desta forma tens os elementos numa posição absoluta em relação ao seu elemento envolvente que é a `div` com a classe de CSS `slide`.
3. #### A imagem

   A tua imagem deve ficar dentro do elemento que a envolve de forma controlada, particularmente devido ao IE8:

   ```css
   .slide_img img {
       position: relative; /* relative e não absolute */
       top: 25%;
       width:100%;
   }
   ```
4. #### Fundo do Slider / Cor da Moldura

   As tuas bordas estão a branco no Internet Explorer 8 porque o mesmo não reconhece nenhuma declaração feita e acaba por aplicar:

   ```css
   background: none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%
   ```

   **Onde tens:**

   ```css
   #slider {
       background: #1d1d1d;
       background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
       background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1d1d1d 0%, #222222 6%, #1e1e1e 100%);
       background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1d1d1d), color-stop(6%,#222222), color-stop(100%,#1e1e1e));
       background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1d1d1d 0%,#222222 6%,#1e1e1e 100%);
       background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1d1d1d 0%,#222222 6%,#1e1e1e 100%);
       background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1d1d1d 0%,#222222 6%,#1e1e1e 100%);
       background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1d1d1d 0%,#222222 6%,#1e1e1e 100%);
       filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1d1d1d', endColorstr='#1e1e1e',GradientType=0 );

   }
   ```

   **Deverá estar:**

   ```css
   #slider {
       background-color: #1d1d1d;
   }
   ```

   Todos os efeitos são imperceptíveis dado o pouco espaço para os apresentar e se querem compatibilidade e coerência com navegadores antigos, atribui uma cor de fundo e dá o assunto por arrumado.

## Resultado

Como podes verificar pela captura de tela em baixo apresentada, se realizares as alterações que indiquei removendo os estilos que eu não referi e aplicando os que estão referidos nesta resposta em cada um dos elementos indicados, ficas com o assunto resolvido para o Internet Explorer 8!

[image: Captura de Tela Internet Explorer 8 após alterações]

<sup>**Nota:** Imagem no tamanho real, clica com o botão direito do rato sobre a mesma e escolhe para abrir a mesma sozinha de forma a visualizares em condições.</sup>

## Observação setas de navegação

As setas de navegação estão exactamente com uma diferença de 30 pixeis em relação aos restantes navegadores.

Se após as alterações a única coisa que estiver fora do lugar forem as setas, avisa que também se dá um jeito a isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, deu uma ajuda grande, vou fazer as alterações aqui. Eu fiz aqui algumas e não centralizou, vou ver ao certo o que está faltando, observar se tem mais coisas do CSS que está quebrando, esperar pra ver

Answer (score 1):

Bom, pre isso eu sempre uso o cycle2. Ele tem funcionado sempre do do IE7 ao IE11 e nos navegadores Opera, Safari, Chrome e Firefox... é só com esses que eu trabalho e prometo entregar o site funcionando igual em todos...

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php

pra quem não sabe o cycle se propõe a ser um slideshow universal-browser, ou seja pra funcionar em qualquer navegador...

Comment: É cara, se eu tivesse encontrado esse, o problema já estava resolvido, só precisaria ajustar o controle, que é o problema que estou tendo agora com o IE, que quando mexe com a resolução mexe com as setas.
Bem, já deixo guardado para os próximos slides, parece que o controle é bem legal sobre o plugin

Comment: para ajustar os controles a minha dica é bem simples, crie seu slideshow dentro de uma div com position:relative; depois crie dentro dele uma com position:absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -(metade da width da div)px; assim voce terá ele perfeitamente centralizada, depois você cria os controles dentro dela e usa position:absolute para posicionar no local exato... o position:absolute sempre é em relação a div pai que tiver um position definido...

Comment: kkk, cara, nem prestei atenção, pensei que tinha corrigido, só que quando muda a resolução que dai não mantem centralizado... vou tentar usar esse plugin mesmo e ver como ajusto o controle